# Validation of viewstate MAC failed (no web garden or web farm) when set ViewStateUserKey

Tags: iis-7, asp.net

I deployed an asp.net webforms website to a machine running Windows WebServer 2008 and IIS 7.  The AppPool uses Framework 4, integrated pipeline, running under the identity of a domain user.  I am **not** running a web farm or web garden.  The web site has only one binding, to http port 80.

I get the "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" when posting back any page except the login page.

In this application we are setting the ViewStateUserKey to Session.SessionID in the code behind for every page except the login page.  When I comment this line out (ie, when I stop setting ViewStateUserKey) the error disappears.

The error also disappears when I set "enableViewStateMAC" to false.

Everywhere I have searched for this error the advice is to look at the machineKey.  I've tried using the default auto-generated machine keys and defined machine keys (examples below) and also tried removing the machineKey tag from the web.config, with no success.

This application is running successfully on a different server (also Windows Web Server 2008, IIS 7, framework v4).  The successfull application sets ViewStateUserKey to SessionId, and the machineKey is similiar to the 3rd example below, with defined decryption and validation keys.

I'm befuddled why this application will run fine on Server "A", but has invalid ViewState on Server "B".  If anyone has a suggestion on how to debug this issue I would much appreciate it.

```
<machineKey decryption="Auto" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1" validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />

<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1" validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />

<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" validationKey="..." />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that the Session cookie actually exists and that it's being sent with every request?  IIRC accessing SessionID if there is no existing session will just return a new value with every request.

You may also want to look at what the File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET Web Forms Project templates do in Visual Studio 2012 / 2013.  Specifically, look at **Site.Master.cs** in the new project template.  That code uses a separate (non-Session) cookie precisely to avoid the problems inherent with trying to maintain Session within an application.

Using this approach also allows you to put anti-CSRF defenses in your Login.aspx page, so that page is also protected.

Comment: Oddly enough, I am no longer having the problem (the application is setting ViewStateUserKey to Session.SessionId successfully now, after simply running on the server for about 24 hours).  But your observation is spot on; I must have been losing session before for some d---ed reason, and I appreciate your pointing me to the new anti-CSRF defense for webforms that avoids using Session.